# Understanding and mitigating Firebase Usage and Billing Fees

Tags: ios, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have tried my best to understand Firebase's usage and billing, but I found I only got more confused. For reference, I use the following Firebase Services in the project in question:

1. Realtime Database
2. Firestore
3. Authentication
4. Cloud Functions
5. Cloud Messaging

A few notes, I do update the Real-time Database frequently, I as well have a simple Firebase Functions method deployed, which is triggered (iOS Notification Trigger) whenever a change happens to the Real-time Database.

With that being said, all the services are within the Free Tier threshold:

[image]

But I still get billed, not much, but on a daily basis nonetheless.

[image]
[image]
[image]

I used to empty my buckets, and that would lower the billing a little, but after a recent Firebase Functions update, it automatically clears buckets now.

Questions:

1. What actions correlate to these costs? (frequency of Firebase Functions triggers, Size of deployed methods, etc.)
2. How can I mitigate these costs?
3. Do these costs scale with more users?

Comment: I would suggest for you to reach out to Firebase support https://firebase.google.com/support/troubleshooter/contact for assistance as this will require access to your project to further troubleshoot/check on your inquiries.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because billing and usage questions should be directed to Firebase support.